# Testing onClose callback which is triggered by clicking outside component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

The popup has a click away listener which closes it when a click event occurs outside the component. I need to test that the popup has closed.

```
it.only('clicking outside popover calls on close callback ', async () => {
    const onCloseCallback = jest.fn();
    const { queryByTestId, getByTestId, getByLabelText } = render(
      <Popup
        onClose={onCloseCallback}
      />
    );

    fireEvent.click(document);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(queryByTestId('Popup')).toBeNull();
      expect(onCloseCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
```

The Popup.tsx component

```
<Popper
      open={open}
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      data-testid="Popup"
      placement="bottom-end"
      modifiers={{
        arrow: {
          enabled: true,
          ref: arrowRef
        },
        flip: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }}>
      <span className={classes.arrow} ref={arrowRef} />
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
        {children}
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </Popper>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: For some reason, once I removed Async from the wrapper, added async waitFor on the element and then also removed act (I had act in my test case). This started working fine.
Try removing async and then test. Please note I do not understand why it works for me like that. Will love if someone can shed light on this.

Comment: Also, try asserting if the element is **not.toBeVisible()** rather than calling the function, that should be the correct assertion for clickAway activity right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why.
But I turned out make it work with

```js
test("When click on cart, should show cart popover, click somewhere should close cart popover", async () => {
    // const popoverCart = screen.getByTestId("popoverCart");
    // expect(popoverCart).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(cart);
    expect(screen.getByRole("popoverCart")).toBeInTheDocument();

    //Click again to close cart
    fireEvent.click(window);
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.queryByRole("popoverCart")).not.toBeVisible()
    );
    // expect(queryByTestId(/popoverCart/i)).toBeNull()
  });
```

Just a reference you guys.